# WAMP will not change MySQL version

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

This happened yesterday out of nowhere - it was working fine then suddenly decided to stop working.

When I left click the WAMP icon, it's telling me that I'm using version 5.7. But when I open the MySQL log file, it tells me I am using version 8. I've tried changing it to version 8 at then back to version 5.7 but it always says I'm on 5.7, and the log file always says I'm using version 8.

I've tried restarting all services, as well as refreshing. Nothing has worked.

The MySQL section of the **wampmanager.conf** reads:

```
mysqlVersion = "8.0.21"
mysqlConfDir = "."
mysqlConfFile = "my.ini"
mysqlExeDir = "bin"
mysqlExeFile = "mysqld.exe"
mysqlServiceInstallParams ="--install-manual wampmysqld64"
mysqlServiceRemoveParams ="--remove wampmysqld64"
mysqlServiceCmd = "mysqld.exe"
[mysqloptions]
mysqlPortUsed ="3306"
mysqlUseOtherPort ="off"
mysqlUseConsolePrompt = "off"
mysqlConsolePrompt= "\U-MySQL\v-['\d']>"
mysqlPortOptionsMenu= "on"
```

And the MySQL log says it's running version 8.

The WAMP tray however shows:

[image: wamp control panel settings]

I'm able to access my projects that use v8, but not the ones that use v5.7.

Similarly, my PHP version is not being correctly displayed in the WAMP tray. It reports as being version 5.6.4, and I can change it to version 7.4.9 (i.e. the projects I'm working on understand that the latest version of PHP is being used), but the tray still says it's on 5.6.4.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Any chance you've got both versions installed?

Comment: @ADyson I do have both versions installed, and I flick between them every now and then for different projects. This hasn't been an issue for me until recently though

Comment: Ok. So maybe the one that WAMP sees is 5.7, and the log file is for the v8 one? It's hard to tell, you have only provided minimal details. Also, what precisely isn't working? Are you unable to access one or both of the instances? I think you'll need to provide some more context if we're going to be able to help you.

Comment: Apologies, if I've been vague it's only because I don't know what details are important to solving the issue. I've updated my question with some more details.

Comment: Did you try `right click wampmanager->refresh`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have, no luck!

Comment: Go here [to WAMPServer the backup repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) and download the `Checks VC++ packages installed`  from the TOOLS section at the bottom of the page. RUn that, does it tell you you are missing one or more MSVC Runtime libraries?

Comment: @RiggsFolly All packages are installed correctly, it says

Comment: @ADyson any ideas based on the updated question details? Still no luck, considering just reinstalling wamp

Comment: If you do that please remember to backup all your databases and make sure your site code is also safe

Answer (score 0):

Right click on wampserver icon and select "Restart from zero". After it reboots, select the right version the normal way and it should work.